# Why is my integral with the error function not being evaluated?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions, assumptions

I'm new to Wolfram Mathematica and I was trying to evaluate this integral in particular:

$$\int_{0}^{x}\frac{e^t \operatorname{erf}(\sqrt{t})\sqrt{\pi t}+1}{\sqrt{\pi t x -\pi t^2}}\mathrm dt$$

The code I tried first was:

```
Integrate[(E^t*Erf[Sqrt[t]]*Sqrt[Pi*t] + 1)/Sqrt[Pi*t*x - Pi*t^2], {t, 0, x}]
```

But the output just returns the input; what am I doing wrong? I tried using `Assumptions -> x > 0` but it doesn't work either. Can someone help me?

Comment: "the output just returns the input" - that means *Mathematica* doesn't know what to do with it. Did you have any reason to expect a closed form?

Comment: You need to use `E` rather than `e`; however, it still does not evaluate.

Comment: @J.M. I solved the half derivative of $e^x$ and I wanted to solve the half derivative of the answer as well to see if it checked out. So basically what I'm trying to do is to find the half derivative of $\frac{e^x erf(\sqrt{x})\sqrt{\pi x}+1}{\sqrt{\pi x}}$

Comment: @BobHanlon Thank you, fixed it...  It's sad that it doesn't work.

Comment: If you have access to version 13.1, you could try looking at `FractionalD[Exp[x], {x, 1/2}]` or `CaputoD[Exp[x], {x, 1/2}]`, for instance. Anyway, you should put that information in your question.

Comment: @PabloArboleya:  Ummm... what is a "half derivative"?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork It's the fractional derivative with order = 1/2.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: You could also try [the `FractionalD` resource function](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/FractionalD).

Comment: Well, Erc integrals have some problems with Mathematica. Not even with Rubi it can be solved. https://github.com/RuleBasedIntegration/Rubi/issues/46

Answer (score 2):

[Re-expressing in terms of the regularized incomplete gamma function](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/GammaRegularized/03/01/02/0004/) makes things work:

```
Assuming[x > 0, Integrate[Exp[t] (1 - GammaRegularized[-1/2, t])/Sqrt[x - t], {t, 0, x}]]
   E^x Sqrt[π]
```

Nevertheless, *Mathematica* should still have been smart enough to do something about this; you should perhaps [report this to Support](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/?topic=feedback).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we want to find an anti derivative of e^x.  We might try this.
[image]
Which Gives
`e^t - 1`
That's not wrong, but not what we really want, so instead we do this:
[image]
which gets us the `e^t` without the constant.

Now, if we take the fractional integral of e^t from 0 to x using Cauchy's formula
[image]
we get  [image] the derivative of which you have already found to be [image]

However, like above, if we change limits of integration in Cauchy's formula to go from negative infinity to x:
[image]
we instead get just `e^x` as the half antiderivative of `e^x` and therefore `e^x` is also the half derivative of `e^x`.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3472151/two-definitions-of-the-half-derivative-of-ex-dont-match-whos-right
https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath616/kmath616.htm